# MySQL date format to string

Tags: mysql

I have a dateformat but to display on front end I would like to display the data like so.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('5,2013','%m,%Y');
```

The result I would like to generate is `'May 2013'`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you storing dates as string values? Mysql has dedicated data types for date and time values: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html

When using date, you can easily use DATE_FORMAT and set %m,%Y as formatting (second argument).

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is good to add a working example or a few crucial lines, it makes it much easier to understand your answer. Like: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('5,2013','%m,%Y'), '%b %Y')`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT replace(date_format(str_to_date('5,2013','%m,%Y'),'%M-%Y'),'-',' ');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25720423)

Answer (score 0):

As to the format just read the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format. You need an uppercase M for the month name. And use `DATE_FORMAT` to get from a date to a string.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE '2013-05-01', '%M %Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have `5,2013` stored in your database, you need to use `DATE_FORMAT` after parsing the string:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('5,2013','%m,%Y'), '%b %Y')
```

Why? Because it seems you don't have a date type stored in the database. So you parse it to date using `STR_TO_DATE`. This give you the default date format. `DATE_FORMAT` let you apply other formattings on it.

All avaliable formatting values are documented here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

In general, I would recommend to think about storing date objects instead of custom date strings like `5,2013`. This avoids those castings, because you could directly use `DATE_FORMAT`. It also has benefits on filtering/ordering and performance. Using date types, you could easily sort by it or filter e.g. everything in month X.

I don't say its not possible with custom strings like `5,2013` but would be more complex and could result in bad performance if the db grows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions:
 
[`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the string (after concatenating the prefix `'1'` to your string) to a valid date and then
 
[`date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to reformat the date:

```
SELECT date_format(str_to_date(concat('1,', ?),'%d,%m,%Y'), '%b %Y');
```

Replace `?` with your string.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k6v2QfD8EoN7Je3i9cfbLL/0).
Result:

```
May 2013
```